# How to pass a function as an object instead of a function?

Tags: c#, vb.net, function, object

I'm trying to give a default value to the register property method. This required a function, but passed as an object(delegate?). Here's the code:

```
protected static propertydata registerproperty(string name, Type type, Func<object> createDefaultValue)
{
    return RegisterProperty(name, type, createDefaultValue, false, null);
}
```

I want to call that registerproperty method, but I don't know how I can do that in VB.net. I just need to pass along a new Person object and I thought this was the way to go:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ItemsProperty As PropertyData = RegisterProperty("Items", GetType(IEnumerable(Of Person)), Function() new Person())
```

This is a function passed as a function, but I need it to pass as an object.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Use the `AddressOf` operator. The [documentation on VB delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx) contains many examples.

Comment: The code is roughly correct, the lambda is a proper substitute for `Func<object>`.  Document the Visual Studio version you use.

Comment: [off-topic] Cool to see Raymond at SO.

Comment: The actual issue is that there are 2 overloads, one that accepts a Func<object>, and one that accepts a TValue. In C#, the runtime knows which overload to use (when using () => new Person(), it will use the Func<object> overload, otherwise it will use the TValue overload). However, in VB.NET, it always uses the TValue overload. If there was a way to cast the TDefaultValue to a Func<object>, the issue is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, working with a sub instead of a function resolves the issue, we've solved some problems that way.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ItemsProperty As PropertyData = RegisterProperty("Items", GetType(IEnumerable(Of Person)), Sub() new Person())
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work even for older versions of the framework:

```
Public Shared Function whatever() As propertyData
    registerproperty("item", GetType(IEnumerable(Of Person)), AddressOf GetObject)
End Function

Public Shared Function GetObject() As Person
    return New Person
End Function
```

with VB 2008 or higher you can use what you have:

```
registerproperty("Item", GetType(IEnumerable(Of Person)), Function() New Person)
```

Comment: Lambdas are a language feature (VB 2008 aka VB9 and on for the way it's used here) not a framework feature.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `Func<object> createDefaultValue` means that you have to pass a function which returns an object. You don't have to pass an object.

`Function() new Person()` is a lambda expression, which represents such a function in VB.

`() => new Person()` is the same in C#.

Your `ItemsProperty As PropertyData` will automatically call this function when a default value is required.